# In dpc++ malloc_shared can we share a buffer between 2 gpus

Tags: sycl, intel-oneapi, dpc++

In sycl/dpc++ malloc_shared I am aware that it is possible to create a buffer which could be shared between the host and a single gpu with the below function.

```
void* malloc_shared(size_t num_bytes,
                    const sycl::device& dev,
                    const sycl::context& ctxt);
```

or

```
int *data = malloc_shared<int>(N, q);
```

I wanted to know if something existed that could possibly share the same data/buffer across multiple gpus? Something like the below

```
int *data = malloc_shared<int>(N, q1,q2);
```

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no standardized way of allocating memory on multiple devices using `sycl::malloc_shared`.

If you wish to use the same buffer from between multiple devices (and the host), you need to use `sycl::malloc_host` (the overload taking `sycl::context`), but that will likely have a negative impact on performance.